# Dynamics CRM 2015 For Outlook E-Mail custom fields are not saved

Tags: outlook, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2015

I'm working on a project with Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015. 
We are using the plugin Outlook to synchronize activities between Outlook and the CRM.
In the CRM activities (E-Mail, Appointments) I have added some custom fields:
[image]

Unfortunately, when I create an E-Mail from Outlook and I set the custom fields from the "CRM fields" form and then I send the E-mail, the values of the custom fields are lost as if there were not saved.

Obviously, when the E-mail is synchronized with the CRM, the value are not set into the CRM E-mail neither.

I don't have this problem with Appointments, only with E-mails.

Here my Synchronization method defined into the CRM Server:

- Incoming Email = Server-Side Synchronization or Email Router Outgoing
- Email = Server-Side Synchronization or Email Router Apointments,
- Contacts, and Tasks = Microsoft Dynamics CRM for Outlook

My Outlook Emails options:
[image]

I have Installed the following plug-in CRM2015-Client-KB3072333-ENU-I386.

The Server run on a Windows Server 2012 R2 (64bits)

I played with the synchronization methods and the options, but it didn't change anything. I tried to save the Email before sending, but same problem.

Any idea would be welcome.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you an O365 account?

Comment: No, I'm not a O365 account